# Getting a Bluetooth chip to communicate with Android Smartphone

Tags: bluetooth, android

I wish to develop an Android application for my phone (nexus 4) which needs to get the device to communicate with a Bluetooth chip/receiver and back at regular intervals. When I say 'chip' I mean any form of device/transmitter which is capable of using Bluetooth to receive and send messages to my phone.

Would anyone be able to tell me the hardware I need to get started?

Apologies if my question is vague but I need pointing in the right direction.

Comment: So you only need serial communications (RFCOMM/SPP)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ignacio. I'm not sure what that is - I need a transmitter that can communicate with my android device. The application requires it to ping every 10 minutes - that's all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can essentially use any Bluetooth device that supports SPP (Serial Port Protocol). Some of the most popular are RN-42 based boards like the [Bluetooth Mate Silver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10393). A lot of these are advertised as serial port replacements (UART in on one side - UART out on the other).

On the android side things are relatively simple, although there are some inconsistencies between Android versions. When starting, my approach was to adapt the BluetoothChat sample application. This should be available when you have installed the Android SDK under samples/[platform version]/BluetoothChat. The only trick is to make sure you use the UUID specific to SPP: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

The hardware side is extremely easy - just hook your Bluetooth module up to your microcontroller via the UART and switch the power on. If you need more help on the Android side I found the [Android StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) an very useful place for Bluetooth help.